# Removing extreme values in a vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

So say, I have a = [2 7 4 9 2 4 999]

And I'd like to remove 999 from the matrix (which is an obvious outlier).

Is there a *general* way to remove values like this? I have a set of vectors and not all of them have extreme values like that. prctile(a,99.5) is going to output the largest number in the vector no matter how extreme (or non-extreme) it is.

Comment: Removing outliers is done simply by assigning an empty matrix (`[]`) in their position indices. _Identifying_ outliers, however, is a completely different question, and it really depends on how tolerant you want your strategy to be. But in that case, this question would belong to [math.stackexchange.com](http://http://math.stackexchange.com), not SO. By the way, how about marking a few previous answers as accepted, to show that you care?

Comment: Does [1 2 3 4 ... 998 999] have an extreme value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several way to do that, but first you must define what is "extreme'? Is it above some threshold? above some number of standard deviations? 
Or, if you know you have exactly `n` of these extreme events and that their values are larger than the rest, you can use `sort` and the delete the last `n` elements. etc...

For example `a(a>threshold)=[]` will take care of a threshold like definition, while `a(a>mean(a)+n*std(a))=[]` will take care of discarding values that are `n` standard deviation above the mean of `a`.

A completely different approach is to use the median of `a`, if the vector is as short as you mention, you want to look on a median value and then you can either threshold anything above some factor of that value `a(a>n*median(a))=[]` .

Last, a way to assess an approach to treat these spikes would be to take a histogram of the data, and work from there...

Comment: How is the second case any different from the first case (just set the threshold to `mean(a) + n * std(a))`? By the way, I would use `abs(a) > threshold` to account for large negative values as well.

Comment: taking a mean of a vector where you have one element at 10^9 and the rest at O(1) is a biased measure, espesially if the vector is short. For example, in the vector `a` in the example the mean is 147, and the std is 375. So you need to go to 3 sigma to filter out 999 (where I come from that's a small number). The median is more often a better quick candidate to consider when trying to process out these "cosmic spikes", but of course the best would be to histogram the data in order to get a feel for how to treat it.

Comment: Yes, of course that if the threshold is a function of `a`, then it is biased. What I meant was that the first case and the second case are the same approach from the implementation standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two:

- Sort your matrix and remove n-elements from top and bottom.
- Compute the mean and the standard deviation and discard all values that fall outside:
  `mean +/- (n * standard deviation)`

In both cases n must be chosen by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Filter your signal.

```
%choose the value
N = 10;
filtered = filter(ones(1,N)/N, 1, signal);
```

Find the noise

```
noise = signal - filtered;
```

Remove noisy elements

```
THRESH = 50;
signal = signal(abs(noise) < THRESH);
```

It is better than `mean+-n*stddev` approach because it looks for local changes so it won't fail on a slowly changing signal like `[1 2 3 ... 998 998]`.

Comment: I believe this is the most robust approach indeed. If my signal is not stationary and thus have a large range of values, an outlier is defined not only by its abnormal value, but by where it stands within my signal's history too.